# Using a single push button to start/stop a motor

Tags: motor, relay, control

Is it possible to use a single push button with a N/O and N/C contact on the back to start and then stop the same motor using only relays. The button will be pressed and the motor runs until the button is pressed again which will stop the motor ?

Comment: It is possible, yes if you have the right kind of switch. Remove the 'using only relays and switches' requirement, and you'll have a much better circuit that will actually do what you want. In general, the best arrangement is to use a suitable n-channel mosfet and a cheap microcontroller.

Comment: Thank you - it was a question given at work and claimed that you can do it using a standard push button with additional contacts on the back and relays but it seems impossible to achieve what was claimed using the components stated

Comment: Yes you can do this, it requires I believe two additional relays. They basically toggle each other on and off using a combination of normally open and normally closed contacts on each one

Comment: In industrial applications it's actually more common to use a three position spring return switch, it makes the circuit slightly simpler turn one way to start turn the other way to stop and center does nothing which it always returns to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a [latching+push+button+switch](https://www.google.com/search?q=latching+push+button+switch). If the switch can't handle the motor current then use the switch to operate a relay which will feed the motor.

Be very aware that this arrangement will not unlatch when power is switched off and that the motor will start without warning after any kind of power cut.